# freeswitch call getting abandoned

Tags: asterisk, freeswitch

i have a freeswitch box that successfully handles incoming calls to a certain DID number, but when i call in from another DID number (which happens to be from Asterisk) i get a message that the call is being abandoned

```
sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 Abandoned
```

here is the log

```
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:737 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State HANGUP
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:413 Channel sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 hanging up, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:60 sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 Standard HANGUP, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:737 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State HANGUP going to sleep
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:504 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1388 Send signal sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 [BREAK]
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) Running State Change CS_REPORTING
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:823 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State REPORTING
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:104 sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 Standard REPORTING, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:823 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State REPORTING going to sleep
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:498 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1388 Send signal sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 [BREAK]
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1615 Session 8 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) Locked, Waiting on external entities
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1633 Session 8 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) Ended
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [NOTICE] switch_core_session.c:1637 Close Channel sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 [CS_DESTROY]
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:626 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) Running State Change CS_DESTROY
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:636 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State DESTROY
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:323 sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 SOFIA DESTROY
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:111 sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99 Standard DESTROY
d6ee709e-455e-42d2-a41a-9c12bae0dbd2 2015-08-16 06:07:44.603896 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:636 (sofia/internal/110@99.99.99.99) State DESTROY going to sleep
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [NOTICE] switch_channel.c:1055 New Channel sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b]
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1053 Send signal sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [BREAK]
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1053 Send signal sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [BREAK]
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) Running State Change CS_NEW
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] sofia.c:8834 sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 receiving invite from 212.76.102.123:5060 version: 1.5.15b  64bit
2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] sofia.c:9001 IP 212.76.102.123 Rejected by acl "domains". Falling back to Digest auth.
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:491 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) State NEW
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1053 Send signal sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [BREAK]
2015-08-16 06:07:49.644078 [DEBUG] sofia.c:2067 detaching session 5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [WARNING] switch_core_state_machine.c:572 5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 Abandoned
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [NOTICE] switch_core_state_machine.c:575 Hangup sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [CS_NEW] [WRONG_CALL_STATE]
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [DEBUG] switch_channel.c:3222 Send signal sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [KILL]
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1388 Send signal sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [BREAK]
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) Running State Change CS_HANGUP
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:735 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) Callstate Change DOWN -> HANGUP
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:737 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) State HANGUP
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.064816 [DEBUG] mod_sofia.c:413 Channel sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 hanging up, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:60 sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 Standard HANGUP, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:737 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) State HANGUP going to sleep
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:504 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) State Change CS_HANGUP -> CS_REPORTING
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_session.c:1388 Send signal sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 [BREAK]
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:472 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) Running State Change CS_REPORTING
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:823 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) State REPORTING
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:104 sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5 Standard REPORTING, cause: WRONG_CALL_STATE
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:823 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) State REPORTING going to sleep
5dd18ba2-0880-4f7b-84ca-650cbd4a947b 2015-08-16 06:08:00.084841 [DEBUG] switch_core_state_machine.c:498 (sofia/internal/17185551212@10.0.0.5) State Change CS_REPORTING -> CS_DESTROY
```

the DID provider writes i should disable any authentication, so i tried the instructions here https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Asterisk

i set the apply-inbound-acl and added the allow rule with the ip he provided me

also i set the gateway to not require authentication as follows (though i dont quite understand why this might help, as i dont think freeswitch will check this gateway when a call comes in...)

```
<gateway name="MySipCo"> 
     <param name="realm" value="88.88.88.88"/> 
     <param name="username" value="not-required"/> 
     <param name="password" value="not-required"/> 
     <param name="from-user" value="not-required"/> 
              <param name="expire-seconds" value="600"/> 
     <param name="register" value="false"/> 
     <param name="retry-seconds" value="30"/> 
     <param name="extension" value="1000"/> 
     <param name="context" value="public"/> 
       <param name="auth-calls" value="false"/>
   </gateway>
```

i tried to reload and restart freeswitch but so far no luck. any ideas?

Comment: hi, any ideas anyone? links/pointers? any help would be appreciated. we're stuck with this for a few days now. thanks

Comment: Hi do you figure out? I have the same issue as you. Two phones, 1 and 2. 2 can call 1, However 1 failed to call 2.